# Getting HASH of individual files within folder uploaded to IPFS

Tags: hash, blockchain, ethereum, ipfs

When I upload a folder of `.jpg` files to IPFS, I get the HASH of that folder - which is cool.

But is each individual file in that folder also getting hashed?
And if so, how do I get the hash of each file?

I basically want to be able to upload a whole bunch of files - like 500 images - and do it all at once, or programmatically, and have the hash of each file be returned to me.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes! From the command line you get back the CIDs (*the Content IDentifier, aka, IPFS hash*) for each file added when you run `ipfs add -r <path to directory>`

```
$ ipfs add -r gifs
added QmfBAEYhJp9ZjGvv8utB3Yv8uuuxsDKjv9rurkHRsYU3ih gifs/martian-iron-man.gif
added QmRBHTH3p4W2xAzgLxvdh8VJvAmWBgchwCr9G98EprwetE gifs/needs-more-dogs.gif
added QmZbffnCcV598QxsUy7WphXCAMZJULZAzy94tuFZzbFcdK gifs/satisfied-with-your-care.gif
added QmTxnmk85ESr97j2xLNFeVZW2Kk9FquhdswofchF8iDGFg gifs/stone-of-triumph.gif
added QmcN71Qh56oSg2YXsEXuf8o6u5CrBXbyYYzgMyAkdkcxxK gifs/thanks-dog.gif
added QmTnuLaivKc1Aj8LBf2iWBHDXsmedip3zSPbQcGi6BFwTC gifs
```

the root CID for the directory is always the last item in the list.

You can limit the output of that command to just include the CIDs using the `--quiet` flag

```
⨎ ipfs add -r gifs --quiet
QmfBAEYhJp9ZjGvv8utB3Yv8uuuxsDKjv9rurkHRsYU3ih
QmRBHTH3p4W2xAzgLxvdh8VJvAmWBgchwCr9G98EprwetE
QmZbffnCcV598QxsUy7WphXCAMZJULZAzy94tuFZzbFcdK
QmTxnmk85ESr97j2xLNFeVZW2Kk9FquhdswofchF8iDGFg
QmcN71Qh56oSg2YXsEXuf8o6u5CrBXbyYYzgMyAkdkcxxK
QmTnuLaivKc1Aj8LBf2iWBHDXsmedip3zSPbQcGi6BFwTC
```

Or, if you know the CID for a directory, you can list out the files it contains and their individual CIDs with `ipfs ls`. Here I list out the contents of the gifs dir from the previous example

```
$ ipfs ls QmTnuLaivKc1Aj8LBf2iWBHDXsmedip3zSPbQcGi6BFwTC
QmfBAEYhJp9ZjGvv8utB3Yv8uuuxsDKjv9rurkHRsYU3ih 2252675 martian-iron-man.gif
QmRBHTH3p4W2xAzgLxvdh8VJvAmWBgchwCr9G98EprwetE 1233669 needs-more-dogs.gif
QmZbffnCcV598QxsUy7WphXCAMZJULZAzy94tuFZzbFcdK 1395067 satisfied-with-your-care.gif
QmTxnmk85ESr97j2xLNFeVZW2Kk9FquhdswofchF8iDGFg 1154617 stone-of-triumph.gif
QmcN71Qh56oSg2YXsEXuf8o6u5CrBXbyYYzgMyAkdkcxxK 2322454 thanks-dog.gif
```

**You can it programatically with the core api in js-ipfs or go-ipfs**. Here is an example of adding a files from the local file system in node.js using js-ipfs from the docs for `ipfs.addAll(files)` - https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/FILES.md#importing-files-from-the-file-system

There is a super helpful video on how adding files to IPFS works over at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5zNPwMDYGg

And a walk through of js-ipfs here https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/tree/master/examples/ipfs-101

Comment: Wow! Very thorough answer Sir! Lots of links to dig into - I shall start exploring them immediately - much obliged!